# Translating Cartesian Coordinates from Hand frame to World Frame: ROS & Baxter (python)

Tags: python, ros, inverse-kinematics, kinematics

So I'm working with the baxter robot and using the ROS workspace. The baxter has a camera attached to its arm, from which I can read x,y,z coordinates of certain object, relative to the hand frame.

Once my object is detected, I need its x,y,z coordinate, but from the robot's main frame, so i need to translate from the hand to the robot frame, and given that the robot has 6 degrees of motion, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. I know that I'm supposed to use DH matrices, but could someone try and explain to me how i should proceed?

Comment: DH is almost always unnecessary. You simply need a transformation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There are very active question forums available for [ROS](http://answers.ros.org) and [Baxter Research Robot](https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/forum/#!forum/brr-users). Also http://robotics.stackexchange.com for robotics question. So you better ask this question on one of them.

If I were you I would ask on ROS forum. Using a powerful library called [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) you can easily transform coordinates over the chain of joints. In your case you may still need to figure out the coordinate of the object detected, which would be the focus of the question.